# libtalloc.so missing on AIX (samba install)

Tags: software-installation, samba, aix

```
1:root@SERVER:/root # ldd /opt/freeware/bin/smbclient
/opt/freeware/bin/smbclient needs:
     /opt/freeware/lib/libreadline.a(libreadline.so.5)
     /opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)
     /opt/freeware/lib/libpopt.so
     /opt/freeware/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so
     /opt/freeware/lib/libkrb5.so
     /opt/freeware/lib/libk5crypto.so
     /opt/freeware/lib/libcom_err.so
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
     /opt/freeware/lib/libldap.a(libldap-2.4.so.2)
     /opt/freeware/lib/liblber.a(liblber-2.4.so.2)
Cannot find libtalloc.so
Cannot find libtevent.so
Cannot find libtdb.so
Cannot find libwbclient.so
     /opt/freeware/lib/libz.a(libz.so.1)
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libc.a(posix_aio.o)
     /usr/lib/librtl.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42.o)
     /opt/freeware/lib/libkrb5support.so
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
     /usr/lib/libs.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libssl.a(libssl.so.0.9.8)
     /usr/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.0.9.8)
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
1:root@SERVER:/root # rpm -qa | grep -i client
samba-client-3.6.24-1
1:root@SERVER:/root # oslevel -s
6100-09-06-1543
1:root@SERVER:/root #
```

**Q**: I cannot find the package that provides the "libtalloc.so" file for AIX 6. Is there any? Or there is some kind of trick to avoid that dependency?

Comment: you mean I have to copy it manually? which version of talloc for AIX 6?

Comment: Is there any talloc in a package? I have to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: installed it from AIX package, not RPM:

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # lslpp -L | grep -i samba
  samba.base                3.0.24.0    C     F    Samba for AIX
0:root@SERVER:/root # which smbclient
/usr/bin/smbclient
0:root@SERVER:/root # lslpp -w /usr/bin/smbclient
  File                                        Fileset               Type
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /usr/bin/smbclient                          samba.base            File
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```